# Upload image to Picasa with Objective-C on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, picasa

I was wondering if anyone had any information of code that they have used to upload an image to Picasa. I really only need the code to upload images, I have everything working to get the image feed and view it, but going the other way is giving me a problem.

Google does not really provide any good documentation for how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
GDataServiceGooglePicasaWeb* service =
 [[GDataServiceGooglePicasaWeb alloc] init];

[service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:@"my.account@gmail.com"
 password:@"mypasswd"];

// get the URL for the album
NSURL *albumURL = [GDataServiceGooglePicasaWeb
 picasaWebFeedURLForUserID:@"my.account" albumID:nil
 albumName:@"MyBestPhotos" photoID:nil kind:nil access:nil];

// set a title and description for the new photo
GDataTextConstruct *title, *desc;
title = [GDataTextConstruct textConstructWithString:@"Sunset Photo"];
desc = [GDataTextConstruct textConstructWithString:@"A nice day"];

GDataEntryPhoto *newPhoto = [GDataEntryPhoto photoEntry];
[newPhoto setTitle:title];
[newPhoto setPhotoDescription:desc];

// attach the photo data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/SunsetPhoto.jpg"];
[newPhoto setPhotoData:data];
[newPhoto setPhotoMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];

// now upload it
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchPicasaWebEntryByInsertingEntry:newPhoto
 forFeedURL:albumURL
 delegate:self
 didFinishSelector:@selector(addPhotoTicket:finishedWithEntry:)
 didFailSelector:@selector(addPhotoTicket:failedWithError:)];
```

Source: http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2007/06/picasa-web-albums-meets-google-data.html

Comment: I will check this and let you know how it worked out, except now my boss wants me to use Flickr to do photo uploading and stuff like that. I would prefer to use Picasa, but it's not my decision. :/

Comment: This code worked for the most part, but I had a problem getting an error stating that I was not entering a photoID. To prevent this, I thought I would just make one, up. No such luck. Any suggestions

Comment: Can some one send me code for this. I am not able to even start as I get the code for Mac support not iOS. Also, I do not understand the integration for Google API.